# If $\left.\lambda\right|_r$ is the restriction of $λ$ to the ball of radius $r$, can we show $\left.λ\right|_1\ast\left.λ\right|_1=\left.λ\right|_2$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fubini-tonelli-theorems

This shouldn't be to difficult, but I struggle to obtain the following result:

Let $\lambda$ be a finite nonnegative measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(E)$ of a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space $E$, $$\overline B_r:=\left\{x\in E:\left\|x\right\|_E\le r\right\}$$ and $$\left.\lambda\right|_r(A):=\lambda\left(A\cap\overline B_r\right)\;\;\;\text{for }A\in\mathcal B(E)$$ for $r>0$.

> Are we able to show $\left.\lambda\right|_1\ast\left.\lambda\right|_1=\left.\lambda\right|_2$?

As usual, if $\mu_i$ is a finite signed measure on $\mathcal B(E)$, then $$(\mu_1\ast\mu_2)(A):=(\mu_1\ast\mu_2)\left(\left\{(x,y)\in E^2:x+y\in A\right\}\right)=\int\mu_1({\rm d}x)\mu_2(A-x)\tag1$$ for $A\in\mathcal B(E)$.

Intuitively, we may clearly write $$\overline B_2=\left\{x+y:(x,y)\in\overline B_1\times\overline B_1\right\}\tag2,$$ which should somehow immediately yield the result.

So, how can we prove the desired claim?

Comment: I would say: the answer is "no".  Even in $1$ dimension, the convolution of the uniform measure on $[-1,1]$ with itself is not a uniform measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false. Here is a simple counter-example:

Consider $\mathbb R$. Then $\overline B_1 =[-1,1]$ and  $\overline B_2 =[-2,2]$. It is easy to see that
$$\overline B_2=\left\{x+y:(x,y)\in\overline B_1\times\overline B_1\right\}$$
However, take $A=[0,1]$. The
$$ (\lambda |_1 * \lambda |_1)(A)= (\lambda \otimes \lambda)(\{(x,y) \in [-1,1]^2: 0 \leqslant x+y \leqslant 1 \}) = \frac{3} {2}$$
On the other hand,
$$ \lambda |_2 (A) = 1 $$